# Creating query to show which editor (classic or block) was last used to edit a post/page

Tags: wp-query, block-editor, get-posts

I have a WordPress site that has some pages created/edited in Classic Editor, and some pages that built/edited with Gutenberg/Block Editor.  I am trying to create a report of which pages use each editor.  Is there a meta value that tracks which editor was used to edit a post?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just go by date? Assuming you made a clean switch from classic to Gutenberg?

Otherwise, there's no definitive meta value, but you could just check the post content for common Gutenberg comments, such as `<!-- wp:paragraph -->`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the post type support for editors

post_type_supports($post_type, 'editor');  For classic editor
gutenberg_can_edit_post_type( $post_type ); or use_block_editor_for_post_type( $post_type ); to check the block editor support.

Next create a meta key and change its value to the choice of editor (every time you choose to change the editor.)

'classic_editor_enabled_editors_for_post' you can use this filter if you are using the classic editor plugin.